# Couldn't find record without an ID, Rails 4 and ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am implementing ActiveAdmin to CRUD my app's content. So far so good.
But I am receiving error: Couldn't find Girl without and ID when I am accessing action 'New' in my admin panel.

[image]

My ActiveAdmin controller:

```
controller do

     def create


      @advertisement = Girl.new(girl_params)

       respond_to do |format|
         @advertisement.bypass_humanizer = true

         if @advertisement.save    

             if params[:images]
                 params[:images].each { |image|
                    @advertisement.pictures.create(image: image)
                  }
             end

            format.html  {redirect_to admin_girl_path(@advertisement)}
            format.json  { render :json => @advertisement, :status => :created, :location => @advertisement }

         else

           format.html { render :action => "new"  }
           format.json { render json: @advertisement.errors.full_messages, status: :unprocessable_entity }
         end
      end 

end 

   def new
     @advertisement = Girl.new
   end

  def edit
    @advertisement = Girl.find(params[:id])
  end 

   def update

     @advertisement = Girl.find(params[:id])

     flash[:notice] = 'Girl was successfully updated.' if @girl.update(girl_params)      
     redirect_to :back
 end

   def show
     @advertisement = Girl.find(params[:id])
   end

  def destroy
     @advertisement = Girl.find(params[:id])
     @advertisement.destroy 

           redirect_to :back      
  end


    def girl_params
       # NOTE: Using `strong_parameters` gem
       params.required(:girl).permit(:id,:humanizer_question_id, :_destroy, :confirmed_at,:bypass_humanizer,:humanizer_answer, :identifier, :token,:name, :work1,:subname,:paid, :work2, :check, :can_add_review,:work3, :work4,:smsidentifier,:smsidentifier_confirmation,:provaider, :expiration,:your_ip,:in_blacklist,:admin_confirmed,:country_id, :region_id,:user_id,:phone_number,:image,:terms_of_service,:region,:age,:height,:weight,:description,:description_ru,:email, hour_ids: [], pictures_attributes: [:image], service_ids: [])
    end

end
```

I have no clue to start with. I can't see problem.

What I tried:

Changed `girl_params` to `permit_params :id,:humanizer_question_id,...` then

```
def create


      @advertisement = Girl.new(permited_params[:girl])

end
```

But that didn't solve the issue.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: If stuck, `puts girl_params` will show you what's going on. Or you could use a debugger like pry.

Comment: You haven't told us which line the error is happening on and the `new` method doesn't seem to be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
format.html { render :action => "new"  }
```

try using

```
format.html { redirect_to new_admin_girl_path }
```